# Dependent and Independent Variables of Different Levels

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I am facing with the situation where the dependent variables is student test scores (student level) and the independent variables are school characteristics (school level). And I am trying to see how school characteristics affect student outcome.

Since the LHS and RHS are of different levels, how should I deal with this situation?

- If I regress directly, then the same school characteristics are there for each of the student from the same school - won't this "blow up" the effects of these school-level variables?
- If I aggregate the student test scores for each school and calculate the mean, won't I ignore the variances for student test scores?

I've learned a little bit of hierarchical modeling, but I am sure about whether it's appropriate for this situation.

Thank you!

Comment: Tentatively the answer are no and yes, respectively. Regressing an aggregate effect at the individual level, is a completely standard thing to do, it would directly answer your research question. You could recast the entire model in an hierarchical framework, but you do not need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical linear modeling is appropriate. You can compute this in the [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) package in R.

This R syntax to do this would look something like this:

```
lmer(
  test ~ student.char.1 + school.char.1 + school.char.2 + ... +
  school.char.n + (1 + student.char.1 | school.id),
  data = dataframe
)
```

I'm assuming your test scores are normally distributed, hence the `lmer` function. This specification would allow you to test for the fixed effects of school characteristics.

The two points you make are correct. And for the second, it would lead to an ecological fallacy as you would be calculating the effects of school characteristics not on student test scores, but school test scores, when you intend student test scores.