# How can I account for clusters at different observational levels than the independent variable?

Tags: experiment-design, multilevel-analysis, cluster-sample

My independent variable, $Y_i$, has observations at the group-year level.

However, I know $Y_i$ is not independent for all $i$ because the same individuals will be in a group for several years in a row.

How can I account for these dependencies (cluster by individual, for instance) given that the independent and dependent variables are on different levels?

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282172/dependent-and-independent-variables-of-different-levels) is basically what I'm asking but there are conflicting answers on it.